# Run method periodically in OnCreate

Tags: android

I'm trying to get GPS location every one second once the app starts. Currently I have my code looks like this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    editLocation = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextLocation);
    btnGetLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLocation);
    btnGetLocation.setOnClickListener(this);
    gps = new GPSTracker(GetCurrentLocation.this);
    getLocation();
}

public void getLocation() {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
    final int seconds = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                if (gps.canGetLocation()) {
                    latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                    longitude = gps.getLongitude();
                }
                String body = latitude + "\t" + longitude + "\t" + seconds;
                editLocation.setText(body);
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        };
    };
    new Thread(runnable).start();
}
```

However, it only runs once (when the app starts) and it never run the second time. I'm using the seconds to check if it runs periodically.

UPDATE: 
This is what I got from logcat

> 04-15 11:11:20.137: E/AndroidRuntime(16160): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-3450
>   04-15 11:11:20.137: E/AndroidRuntime(16160): android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
>   04-15 11:11:20.137: E/AndroidRuntime(16160):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:6818)
>   04-15 11:11:20.137: E/AndroidRuntime(16160):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRootImpl.java:1112)
>   04-15 11:11:20.137: E/AndroidRuntime(16160):  at android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild(ViewGroup.java:4484)
>   04-15 11:11:20.137: E/AndroidRuntime(16160):  at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:11353)
>   04-15 11:11:20.137: E/AndroidRuntime(16160):  at android.widget.TextView.invalidateRegion(TextView.java:5378)
>   04-15 11:11:20.137: E/AndroidRuntime(16160):  at android.widget.TextView.invalidateCursor(TextView.java:5321)
>   04-15 11:11:20.137: E/AndroidRuntime(16160):  at android.widget.TextView.spanChange(TextView.java:8581)
>   04-15 11:11:20.137: E/AndroidRuntime(16160):  at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.onSpanAdded(TextView.java:10686)
>   04-15 11:11:20.137: E/AndroidRuntime(16160):  at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendSpanAdded(SpannableStringBuilder.java:979)
>   04-15 11:11:20.137: E/AndroidRuntime(16160):  at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(SpannableStringBuilder.java:688)
>   04-15 11:11:20.137: E/AndroidRuntime(16160):  at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(SpannableStringBuilder.java:588)
>   04-15 11:11:20.137: E/AndroidRuntime(16160):  at android.text.Selection.setSelection(Selection.java:116)
>   04-15 11:11:20.137: E/AndroidRuntime(16160):  at android.text.Selection.setSelection(Selection.java:127)
>   04-15 11:11:20.137: E/AndroidRuntime(16160):  at android.text.method.ArrowKeyMovementMethod.initialize(ArrowKeyMovementMethod.java:302)
>   04-15 11:11:20.137: E/AndroidRuntime(16160):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4434)
>   04-15 11:11:20.137: E/AndroidRuntime(16160):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4283)
>   04-15 11:11:20.137: E/AndroidRuntime(16160):  at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:108)
>   04-15 11:11:20.137: E/AndroidRuntime(16160):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4258)
>   04-15 11:11:20.137: E/AndroidRuntime(16160):  at com.yc.test.GetCurrentLocation$1.run(GetCurrentLocation.java:60)
>   04-15 11:11:20.137: E/AndroidRuntime(16160):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)

and the modified code:

```
Thread checker;

public void getLocation() {
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            while (true) {
                int seconds = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
                try {
                    if (gps.canGetLocation()) {
                        latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                        longitude = gps.getLongitude();
                    }
                    String body = latitude + ", \t" + longitude + "\t"
                            + seconds;
                    editLocation.setText(body);
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
    };
    checker = new Thread(runnable);
    checker.start();
}
```

Comment: Well, you dont have any loop in your `run()`, so the thread ends after single run.

Comment: Also calling `editLocation.setText(body);` is a bed idea, you should not modify UI from non UI thread.

Answer (score 1):

You are only starting a thread which is doing the code once. You need a loop:

```
while(true){
//do your stuff
sleep(1000) // to wait the second
}
```

Comment: @Malluce please post the error/stacktrace that we can help you

Answer (score 1):

I Think this is what you want

```
Thread checker ;
public void getLocation() {
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
            while(true){ // loop forever and check GPS location
                int seconds = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
                try {
                   if (gps.canGetLocation()) {
                       latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                       longitude = gps.getLongitude();
                   }
                   String body = latitude + "\t" + longitude + "\t" + seconds;
                   editLocation.setText(body);
                   Thread.sleep(1000);
               } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
            }// end while
        };
    };
    checker = new Thread(runnable).start();
}
```

call `checker.cancel();` when you want to stop checking

Comment: I changed this but it crashes every time when it's calling a new Thread every one second.

Comment: @Malluce what is in logcat?

Answer (score 0):

So, I haven't got enough rep to comment on Bolics answer :( Look at this answer like a comment please.

"I tried that and the entire app crashes" - Malluce
This is, because when you're looping forever in onCreate(), the app doesn't do anything else.
Thus, you need to create another Thread, as Farnabaz suggested. Maybe use AsyncTask if you'd like to show a progressDialog in the main activity. If you don't need to 'communicate' with the main activity from within that second Thread, you can simply do what Farnabaz suggested.

(I wrote this to explain your errors and the answer. If this is frowned upon because I haven't any "new" facts, please tell me:) )

Comment: Thanks for the input! So I did try Farnabaz's suggestion, however, it crashes every time when it's calling a new Thread every one second. So it will run the first time, then the app will crash.

Comment: not sure if I understand you right...are you creating a new Thread every second? Don't do this, just run the loop in one Thread. Also, what does the logcat say? (yay I can comment :))